# Case when SQL statement into variable

Tags: t-sql, sap-ase

I need to create a variable for a `case when statement` on sybase sql. I have this error from my sql client

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be
>   combined with data-retrieval operations.

What do I need to do to use this variable the right way?

```
DECLARE @OutputName CHAR(50) 
SELECT @OutputName=
(case when (a.M_TRN_TYPE='XSW' or a.M_TRN_TYPE='SWLEG') then 'FXSW'
      when (a.M_TRN_TYPE<>'SWLEG' and a.M_TP_DVCS='C') then 'DCS'
      when a.M_TRN_TYPE<>'SWLEG' and a.M_TP_DVCS<>'C' and SUBSTRING(c.M_SP_SCHED0,1,2)='+1' then 
                                                                                      (case when b.M_DTE_SKIP_1>=a.M_TP_DTEEXP then 'SPOT' else 'OUTR' end)
      when a.M_TRN_TYPE<>'SWLEG' and a.M_TP_DVCS<>'C' and SUBSTRING(c.M_SP_SCHED0,1,2)<>'+1' then 
                                                                                      (case when b.M_DTE_SKIP_2>=a.M_TP_DTEEXP then 'SPOT' else 'OUTR' end)
end),
case when @OutputName='XSW' and 
                (case when c.M_DATESKIP='+1OD' then b.M_DTE_SKIP_1 else b.M_DTE_SKIP_2 end)=a.M_TP_DTEFST 
                      then 0 
                 else a.M_NB
                 end as 'NBI'
from TP_COMPL_PL_REP b
join TP_ALL_REP a on (a.M_NB=b.M_NB and a.M_REF_DATA=b.M_REF_DATA) 
left join DM_SPOT_CONTRACT_REP c on (a.M_NB=c.M_NB and a.M_REF_DATA=c.M_REF_DATA)
```

Comment: `SET @OutputName = (select (case when .....) as outputname) ....`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't combine a `SELECT` which sets a variable with a `SELECT` which returns data on the screen.

You set `@OutputName` to `(case when (a.M_TRN_TYPE='XSW' .. )` but in the same `SELECT` you're also trying to display the results of:

```
case
    when @OutputName='XSW' and 
         (case 
              when c.M_DATESKIP='+1OD' 
                  then b.M_DTE_SKIP_1 
              else b.M_DTE_SKIP_2 
          end)=a.M_TP_DTEFST 
              then 0 
    else a.M_NB
end as 'NBI'
```

You can't have these two in the same `SELECT`, in the format you're using. My recommendation is to split them, one for assigning the variable:

```
DECLARE @OutputName CHAR(50) 
SELECT @OutputName=
(case when (a.M_TRN_TYPE='XSW' or a.M_TRN_TYPE='SWLEG') then 'FXSW'
      when (a.M_TRN_TYPE<>'SWLEG' and a.M_TP_DVCS='C') then 'DCS'
      when a.M_TRN_TYPE<>'SWLEG' and a.M_TP_DVCS<>'C' and SUBSTRING(c.M_SP_SCHED0,1,2)='+1' then 
                                                                                      (case when b.M_DTE_SKIP_1>=a.M_TP_DTEEXP then 'SPOT' else 'OUTR' end)
      when a.M_TRN_TYPE<>'SWLEG' and a.M_TP_DVCS<>'C' and SUBSTRING(c.M_SP_SCHED0,1,2)<>'+1' then 
                                                                                      (case when b.M_DTE_SKIP_2>=a.M_TP_DTEEXP then 'SPOT' else 'OUTR' end)
end)
from TP_COMPL_PL_REP b
join TP_ALL_REP a on (a.M_NB=b.M_NB and a.M_REF_DATA=b.M_REF_DATA) 
left join DM_SPOT_CONTRACT_REP c on (a.M_NB=c.M_NB and a.M_REF_DATA=c.M_REF_DATA)
```

and one for returning the data:

```
SELECT case when @OutputName='XSW' and 
                (case when c.M_DATESKIP='+1OD' then b.M_DTE_SKIP_1 else b.M_DTE_SKIP_2 end)=a.M_TP_DTEFST 
                      then 0 
                 else a.M_NB
                 end as 'NBI'
from TP_COMPL_PL_REP b
join TP_ALL_REP a on (a.M_NB=b.M_NB and a.M_REF_DATA=b.M_REF_DATA) 
left join DM_SPOT_CONTRACT_REP c on (a.M_NB=c.M_NB and a.M_REF_DATA=c.M_REF_DATA)
```